# Schedule task for once in a day on Heroku without Installing any Addon

Tags: heroku

Is it possible that I can run my task on Heroku whenever it restarts everyday or implement it without using any addons? It asks me for credit card and I don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger your task externally by calling your Heroku URL.

For example, configure a cron job somewhere that calls the URL with wget:

*/5 * * * * wget -O /dev/null -q https://yourproject.herokuapp.com